# Avoiding lambda invocation during terraform plan phase

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a lambda which I want to invoke once during terraform apply since it updates a database and should be triggered only once in the apply phase.
My problem is that terraform invokes it during the plan phase as well.
Is there a way to run it only during the apply phase?
Example:

```
data "aws_lambda_invocation" "run_lambda" {
  function_name = "test"

  input = <<JSON
  {}
  JSON
}
```

Comment: Interesting problem. I suspect you cannot restrict this particular resource from invoking the lambda upon plan - it is set up as a data source, so Terraform will "read" it during the plan phase. Since you are writing data with this lambda, you will need something else. Here's a module that I've never used but could be worth trying: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/crisboarna/lambda-invoke/aws/1.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `aws_lambda_invocation` *resource* rather than data source (this tripped me up as well). From the docs:

> This resource only invokes the function when the arguments call for a create or update. In other words, after an initial invocation on apply, if the arguments do not change, a subsequent apply does not invoke the function again. To dynamically invoke the function, see the triggers example below. To always invoke a function on each apply, see the aws_lambda_invocation data source.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function

Answer (score -1):

late for requester but answer for future reference:
Try using `depends_on: [some_resource]` construct in aws_lamdbda_invocation. let the invocation depend on any other resource. If no dependency (which I hardly believe), introduce artificial one, like `time_sleep`. Let execution waits for 1s and make lambda dependant on it.
This way `terraform plan` would not complain.

Comment: I tried 'depends_on = [aws_lambda_function.name]' and 'depends_on = [time_sleep.wait_30_seconds]', and both still result in extra invocations. Are there requirements you haven't listed? Admittedly, I find this a bit difficult to read.